# Private (Raspberry) Data-Server for friends

Tags: python, linux, networking, raspberry-pi

here's my question:
I coded an Application which saves and reads data from an XML-File. This Application is for 5 other people, they can create "Tasks". -> These Tasks will be stored into an XML-File and the other people should be able with their application to get this data. So my idea was to create a Raspberry Server on which the XML-Files will be written on, like a shared Network Drive. So is there a way to create something like this save & privat, so only my friend's application can have access to the Raspberry? Or is this the wrong way to store information? You can also give me just some keywords to look in the internet for it, answers would help me alot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think using a database such as SQLite, Postgres or MySql to store information would be a better idea. The benefit is that you will access and organise data much more easily. 
On the problem of making your application private, you will need to create an authentication layer, where users will need to log in using username and password, this on top, of course, of the security provided by accessing privately your wifi network. I would recommend to use some pre-existing authentication framework, depending on the programming language you will use to implement your application. For example, if you are using python as a programming language, and flask as web application engine, flask already provides some mechanisms to log your users, that will avoid lot of headaches for you. Security and authentication is not an easy problem to solve, nor one that should be underrated. The module I am referring to is called [Flask login](http://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify if this needs to work only within a network or over the internet so I'm going to assume the latter for this answer.

The easiest way to have a safe and private file share among your friends would be to use an existing service like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [Google Drive](https://www.google.co.uk/drive/download/) synced to a folder on each of your friends computers. That way the file sharing and security are all handled for you.

If you don't want them to have to set up Dropbox locally to use your app you could try using the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) (or equivalent) to integrate directly.

If you must own the infrastructure that the files are shared on you could use [CIFS/SMB](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/samba-file-server/) on a Raspberry Pi and set up a file share secured based on user accounts, either just one for the app or one per user which they would use to sign into the app.

From there you could go further and start using Azure or AWS and Active Directory but that may be getting too Enterprise level for what you need.